# Why can't I change permissions for share

Tags: networking, file-sharing

So, I have a external Hard drive that I am trying to share on my network. It is plugged into the usb on my TVpc, and I want to be able to access and change folders and files from my laptop. When I go to change permissions with the GUI, I click the drop down and click to change permissions, but even if I click read and write under guests or other, it will automatically change back to "None."  I have no idea how to fix this and I cant access my files from another computer. any help?!

Comment: Is the external drive formatted in NTFS, FAT or similar? If yes, I don't think Linux permissions work on them. These answers might be interesting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Comment: what protocol are you using to share ? ftp? nfs? cifs ? sshfs? and what file system ?

Comment: @ Bruno: I'm using an NTFS file system so that I would be able to get the files while using windows. It is an external drive after all. I'll take a look at the link, Thanks!

Comment: @ bodhi: I'm not sure what protocol i'm using. I'm a big noob when it comes to networking on linux. I did install samba to set up the share. Also, I noticed that when I scan my network with my laptop, I see a "Windows" network, which is weird because none of my computers have windows. should I be restarting my wifi network or something?

Answer (score 0):

"It is plugged into the usb on my TVpc"

The access permissions are set by whatever is "sharing" out your disk filesystem on that machine.

You cannot change permissions on your remote disk filesystem from another computer unless the TVPc gives you permission to do so.

Please be security-wise and do not just make the permissions on your disk world writeable (or perhaps even world readable if there is sensitive material on the disk) to anybody who can access the local network.

If the PcTV is sharing using CIFS/SMB protocol, you could apply settings in the smb.conf file to require authentication with a password to some generic account eg "nobody"   On your other PC you can easily setup autofs to automagically mount the exported CIFS share with the user/password combination in a secure root only readable file.

The same is also possible with NFS exports and autofs mouting of them.

The threat now is not just via the local ethernet/wireless network but also now via signals received by the TV itself.

It has been discovered that it is possible via the broadcast Hibb TV protocol (this is a service transmitted over the air and via satellite) to get access to TVs and to perhaps even open devices on the local network.

http://www.itnews.com.au/News/345632,hbbtv-holes-make-tellys-hackable.aspx